# WPF Mouse Over

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mouseevent

What is the best way to link a method when the mouse over event is fired?

An example.

when a mouse hovers over a button. A method fires such as count.

So as long as the mouse is over the button, the count will keep on incrementing.

How will i connect a mouse over event to a method? Using Xaml?!

ANY IDEAS?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is via an attached property, especially if you want to reuse this capability.

Expression Blend's `Behavior<T>` class makes this simple.  You'll need the the Blend SDK, but then you can use behaviors directly.  Here's a [blog post showing an example](http://blogs.msdn.com/expression/archive/2009/07/15/a-look-at-some-advanced-behaviors-features.aspx).

This allows you to assign an attached behavior in XAML.  Many MVVM frameworks have an implementation that uses this approach, such as the [LifetimeEvents in Cinch](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/CinchII.aspx).

Comment: Here's another link: http://blog.kirupa.com/?p=378   I walks through how to do this in more detail, using the Expression SDK options (InvokeCommandAction and a custom Behavior<T>)