# How do I use wpf events from xaml in my viewmodel without code-behind?

Tags: wpf, events, xaml, viewmodel

In WPF via XAML through to my viewModel, **I want to detect mouse move on a Canvas,** and react to it only when the left mouse button is pressed.  Specifically I want to **get the event from a method in my viewModel,** including mouse position and mouse button states.  Can someone help me with this?

I know I could use regular WPF events in code-behind, but doing that would be "surrendering" in my opinion, surrendering to the XAML learning curve, so that is last-resort.

I found this question, but I can't afford Expression Blend, so it does not help me:
[WPF Mouse Over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429597/wpf-mouse-over)

I looked in to

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Canvas.MouseMove"> . . .,
```

but that looks like it is only for animations.

It seems like this would be a common thing for people to want to do, but I can't find anything on it.

Comment: Regarding your equating of code-behind to "surrendering", allow me to disagree in this case.  This may be a valid case for code behind.  Code behind is there to make it easier to automate your view.  Unless your business logic is affected, the code in the code-behind of your view is fine to have.  Don't overcomplicate it.

Comment: Well, let me agree with you disagreeing with me.  If this is a clear case where code-behind is appropriate, then, yes, I am not surrendering.  I guess I meant, resorting to code-behind without seeking a XAML-only way first (if there is one), that would be surrendering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an attached behavior of canvas that accepts the command and raise it and your view model will subscribe to that command and perform the action.

Answer (score 0):

first: you dont need Expression Blend, you just need the SDK

or if you look at mvvm light framework there is also a EventToCommand behavior